# how to display the closest pair product in array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class my
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t;
        int a[] = new int[5];
        int l = a.length;
        int prod[] = new int[100];
        int index[] = new int[100];
        int n;
         System.out.println("enter a elements into array ");
         for(int i = 0;i<5;i++)
         {
             a[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }
         for(int i = 0 ;i<4;i++)
         {
             for(int j = 0;j<(4-i);j++)
             {
                 if(a[j]>a[j+1])
                 {
                     t = a[j];
                     a[j] = a[j+1];
                     a[j+1] = t;
                    }
             }
         }
        System.out.println("enter a number");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0;i<l-1;i++)
        {
            prod[i] = a[i]*a[i+1];
            index[i] = a[i];
            index[i+1]=a[i+1];
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<l;i++)
        {
            if(prod[i]!=0)
           System.out.println(prod[i]);

        }

        for(int i = 0;i<l-1;i++)
        {
            if(n>prod[i]&&n<=prod[i+1])
            System.out.println(index[i+1]+"\t"+index[i+2]); 

        }
    }
}
```

if want to display the closest pair product in array, which nearest to the entered number. but when i entered array element 1, 2 ,3, 5, 4 
and after enter the array i am entering number 8 it is display 3, 4 pair from array instead of 5,2. answer would be 5,2 because the product of 5 * 2 is 10 which is closest to entered number is 8.

Comment: I think that `2 * 4` is even closer to 8 than `5 * 2`...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is that it is just calculating the product of two consecutive elements and than your are simply comparing that with the product of other elements, which is not a correct way.

Since you sort the array a better way to do it is, by using the logic of binary search. And the logic that the product of pair closest to x will have the least difference.

The algorithm which you can use is as followed:

```
1. Make a variable difference and initialize to Integer.MAX_VALUE;
2. Now traverse the array from both the direction, i.e set index of left = 0, and right = arr.length -1.
3. Loop while left < right.
   (a) If  abs((arr[left] * arr[right]) - x) < difference  
       then update difference and result 
   (b) if((arr[left] * arr[right]) <  x)  then
       left++
   (c) Else right--
```

> Time Complexity : O(nlog(n))

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have so many loops and so many variables in your solution. You also don't need to sort the array `a`.

In pseudo code:

```
var a[]
var n
var closest = MAX_INTEGER
var closest_i
var closest_j

for i in range [0, a.length)
    for j in range [i + 1, a.length)
        var distance = abs(a[i] * a[j] - n)
        if distance < closest
            closest = distance
            closest_i = i
            closest_j = j
```

Note that this has `O(n)` time complexity.